# ASP.NET Core multiple file upload, SQL Server identity column Issue

Tags: sql-server

I've an issue with multiple file upload in ASP.NET Core. When I'm uploading multiple files at once, I'm getting this error from the SQL Server database :

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'photos' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

My code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Photos photos)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(4);
            var photoAddDate = photos.PhotoAddedData = date.ToString("yyyy- 
            MM-dd','HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            foreach (var file in photos.FormFile)
            {
                var filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, 
                Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                photos.PhotoPath = "/" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                photos.PhotoPath = filePath;
                _context.Photos.Add(photos);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
      }
```

I then tried with this code :

```
var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT[dbo].[photos]ON;");
_context.Photos.Add(photos);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT[dbo].[photos] OFF;");
transaction.Commit();
```

and got another error :

> SqlException: Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'photos' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much

Comment: If you are going to create your own key, don't use Identity.  If you want SQL Server to assign the IDs, don't mess with it.  `Just because can you does mean should you`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is merely a problem of non-unique IDs trying to be inserted and any answers are unlikely to be of long term use to other users.

Comment: i don't want to mess with sql, i want to upload multiple files to database

Comment: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT[dbo].[photos]ON;` is `mess[ing] with sql`